# DeleteCases/ReplaceAll and PatternSequence

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I thought it must be

```
DeleteCases[{1,2,{a,{b,3,7}},4,5,6},PatternSequence[3,7],Infinity]
{1,2,{a,{b}},4,5,6}

ReplaceAll[{1,2,{a,{b,3,7}},4,5,6},PatternSequence[3,7]->100]
{1,2,{a,{b,100}},4,5,6}
```

But it was wrong, in fact, `DeleteCases` and `ReplaceAll` didn't do anything.

```
DeleteCases[{1,2,{a,{b,3,7}},4,5,6},PatternSequence[3,7],Infinity]
{1,2,{a,{b,3,7}},4,5,6}

ReplaceAll[{1,2,{a,{b,3,7}},4,5,6},PatternSequence[3,7]->100]
{1,2,{a,{b,3,7}},4,5,6}
```

I've used `PatternSequence` before and worked, but today it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

After seeing a comment :
Now I can do it with `ReplaceAll`.

```
ReplaceAll[{1, 2, {a, {b, 3, 7}}, 4, 5, 
  6}, {x___, PatternSequence[3, 7], y___} -> {x, y}]
```

(*x___ and y___ must be triple underlines)

```
{1, 2, {a, {b}}, 4, 5, 6}
```

But is it also possible to change

```
{1, 2, {a, {b, 3, 7}}, 4, 5, 6}
```

to

```
{1, 2, {a, {b}}, 4, 5, 6}
```

using `DeleteCases` ?

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

I think in such case, a technique similar to

```
{x___, (*WnatToDelete*), y___} -> {x, y}
```

is **unavoidable**.

Also note that `SequenceReplace` neither can do this because there is no

level concept for `SequenceReplace`(always level 1.)

Comment: Note the second point of [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternSequence.html): "PatternSequence can appear anywhere inside a pattern but cannot be the only element of a pattern."

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question.

Comment: "I thought it might be... But it was wrong" -- I'm confused. I don't know what you thought it might be or why it was wrong.

Comment: Thank you, my English was not good, I updated.

Comment: No you can not delete 3 and 7 from {b,3,7} because b needs to be matched and therefore deleted.

Comment: Thank you, looks it's not possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question seems to be drifting, and I'm not sure if it's a question about usage of a particular function or about how to achieve a particular objective.